# eloquent orm select where and then update

Tags: php, lumen

I have some code

```
public function addvote($id,$varia){
    $pollsres = Pollsres::where('poll_id', '=',$id)->where('poll_variant','=',$varia)->get();
    // and poll_variant = ?',[$id,$varia])->get();
    if($pollsres->isEmpty()){
        $pollres = new Pollsres();
        $pollres->poll_id = $id;
        $pollres->poll_variant = $varia;
        $pollres->poll_count = 1;
        $pollres->save();
    }else{
        //return response()->json($pollsres);
        var_dump($pollsres);
    }

}
```

In db i have 1 record $id = 1 and $varia = 1 but have i can update $pollsres->poll_count i have error, if i update $pollsres[0]->poll_count i update all record not only why have where expression (testing whith 2 record in db)

i whant check if i have record in db whith where if not add new if have edit this record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your table does not have `primary key`.

You need adding `auto increment` primary key for you table, because [Laravel/Lumen does not support composite primary key (i.e: 2 primary keys or more)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355#issuecomment-115426172).

And then the problem will be solved.